# Why won't the javascript alerts pop up in an ASP classic Select Case branch?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

Why won't the JavaScript alerts pop up in an ASP classic Select Case branch?
When I put in the Response.End statements and run through the checkout process the JavaScript alert's do their thing.. but when I take them out and they are immediately followed by a Redirect... the alerts do not popup. Any idea why?

```
If strResponse <> "000" Then
Select Case strResponse
    Case "701"
        %>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("The customer is under 18 years of age based upon the date of birth.");
        </script>
        <%
        'Response.End
        Response.Redirect strRedirectCheckout
    Case "702"
        %>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("The billing address is outside the United States.");
        </script>
        <%
        'Response.End
        Response.Redirect strRedirectCheckout
    Case "707"
        %>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("The account holder does not have sufficient credit available for the transaction amount.");
        </script>
        <%
        'Response.End
        Response.Redirect strRedirectCheckout
    Case Else
        %>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Unable to obtain an authorization\nClick OK to be redirected back to checkout and please choose another form of payment");
        </script>
        <%
        'Response.End
        Response.Redirect strRedirectCheckout
End Select

Else ' if strResponse does == '000'; SUCCESS!!!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a Response.Redirect sends a message to the browser to start navigating to the page indicated. If you want them to see the popup first, after the alert just stay in JavaScript and use document.location.href=.....

Answer (score 4):

When you use Response.Redirect, you are affecting the response code of the request.  When a browser loads a piece of content, it gets a return code such as 200 or 401 that indicates the status of the request.  A Response.Redirect sends a return code that causes the browser to not render anything it received, but redirect the response instead.  Without it, the browser gets a 200 response and renders what it received.

The HTTP response codes are detailed at http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

See especially

> 10.3 Redirection 3xx
>
> This class of status code indicates that further action needs to be
>   taken by the user agent in order to fulfill the request.

Essentially, you can't instruct the browser (via the HTTP status code) to both render a page and redirect it somewhere else at the same time.  These are mutually exclusive, and redirection wins out over rendering.

Answer (score 1):

I will start to wonder why do you put **server validation** mixed up with **client validation** in the first place...

**Client Validation** is the validation that takes place BEFORE any action is done to the page it self, in other words, before the actual POST of the form.

**Server Validation** should perform the same but in the server side and should only issue a normal message that, for example, could fillup a `<div>`

From your example I would do this:

---

1 - *Add client side validation*

Let's assume that you **ARE USING jQuery** (to facilitate code as the idea is only to show you the path to take...), and that you have a POST button, coded as

```html
<input type="submit" id="btnSave" value="Save" />
```

add this to the end of the page, before the `</body>` tag:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

  $("form").submit(function() {
    // before the form submit, do this:

    var msg = '';

    if(parseInt($(".input-age-year").val()) < 1994)
        msg += '\nThe customer is under 18 years of age based upon the date of birth.';
    if($(".input-country").val() != 'USA')
        msg += '\nThe billing address is outside the United States.';
    if(parseInt($(".hidden-credit").val()) < parseInt($(".input-amount").val()))
        msg += '\nThe account holder does not have sufficient credit available for the transaction amount.';
    // etc...

    if(msg === '') 
       // message is empty, all is well, let's submit the form
       return true;
    else {
       // there is an error message to show
       alert(msg); // I would show an error div with the message instead though...
    }

  });

});

</script>
```

By the way, you should see the [**jQuery Validation Plugin**](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), it's way better!

---

2 - *Do your Server Validation*

This is always important as you can submit without having javascript enabled, and it helps narrow down potential "hackers"

Do the same but redirect to the same page adding a query string to the URL or use the `Session` object to hold the error (remember to delete it after you display the message in the page)

for example:

```vb
Dim msg As String = ""

If cInt(Request("frm-age-year")) < 1994 Then
    msg = "<br/>The customer is under 18 years of age based upon the date of birth."
End If

' ...

If msg = "" Then
  ' Continue processing ...
Else
  Response.Redirect Request.ServerVariables("URL") & "?error=" & msg
End if
```

and in the `.asp` you have a place like

```asp
<% If Request("error") <> Null Then %>
    <div class="error"><%= Request("error") %></div>
<% EndIf %>
```